# Requests in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have a problem with Laravel.

I have created a model and a migration and migrated it. When I want to use it in the controller, it doesn't work and I get an error 500.

This is my controller :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Models\Exposition;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ExpositionsController extends Controller
{
    public function list()
    {
        $expo = Exposition::all();
        return view('expositions', ['dataex'=>$expo]);
    }
}
```

This is my view :

```
@foreach ($dataex as $ex)
<span class="expo1">{{$ex->annee}} : {{$ex->ville}}, {{$ex->salle}}</span>
<span class="expo2">{{$ex->titre}}</span>
@endforeach
```

This is web.php :

```
Route::get('expositions','App\Http\Controllers\ExpositionsController@list');
```

It only works when I use DB instead of Exposition in the public function. Can someone explain that?

Thanks by advance!

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: There might still be log entries in apache's error.log. Please post the error text as well.

Comment: The error is error 500.

Comment: 500 is just the error code, you should find what has caused this error. Check laravel log (in storage-logs).

Comment: Do you have a file named `expositions.blade.php` in your `resources-views` directory?

Comment: Yes. The second code I've posted come from expositions.blade.php.